# Sticky label (header) of listview in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.listview

How to create sticky header in listview in Xamarin cross platform? I have a list of  sorted objects and I want create sticky header when scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is GitHub code for this that you can find [here](https://github.com/himanshudwd765/Xamarin.Forms-StickyHeaderListView/tree/master/StickyHeaderListView)

For iOS this is the Native behaviour

And the Android Renderer is below:

```
public class CustomListViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomListView, Android.Views.View>
{
    Dictionary<string, int> mapIndex;
    StickyListHeadersListView SlistView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

        Android.Views.View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.customListView, null, false);

        //this.AddView(v);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            SlistView = v.FindViewById<StickyListHeadersListView>(Resource.Id.list_employee);
            SetNativeControl(v);

        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // unsubscribe
            //Control.ItemClick -= OnItemClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            // subscribe
            SlistView.Adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(Forms.Context as Android.App.Activity, e.NewElement as CustomListView);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    void OnItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //((CustomListView)Element).NotifyItemSelected(((CustomListView)Element).Items.ToList()[e.Position - 1]);
    }
}
```

Goodluck in case of issues feel free to revert.